# Not able to run a simple doclet program : package com.sun.javadoc does not exist

Tags: java, javadoc, doclet

I am trying to run a simple doclet program, but I am not able to compile it.

```
javac -cp /cygdrive/c/Progra~2/Java/jdk1.8.0_65/lib/tools.jar  A.java
```

But it throws

> A.java:1: error: package com.sun.javadoc does not exist import
>   com.sun.javadoc.ClassDoc;

Where A.java is

```
import com.sun.javadoc.ClassDoc;
public class A {
}
```

I referred it from

http://download.java.net/jdk7u2/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/doclet/overview.html

I know that I am doing a simple mistake but I ma not able to figure it out.
Can anyone please point me out what am I doing wrong

Comment: Did you able to solve this problem ?

Comment: @prime I was able to run but I forgot how I did that

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Tools.jar to the project path. It is not included in the standard installation.

Can I ask why you need com.sun.javadoc? It is in most cases discouraged to use com.sun overall.

Comment: I was following the examples in http://download.java.net/jdk7u2/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/doclet/overview.html

Comment: Is not adding -cp JDKPATH/libs/tools.jar not enough?

Comment: Im not great at using terminals. But isnt cp the copy command? If you want to add the classpath i think it should be like this: javac -classpath JDKPATH/libs/tools.jar ClassName.java

Comment: I recommend getting eclipse or intellij as it makes developing java code a lot simpler.

Comment: -cp is the shortform of -classpath