# Couldn't compile a java doclet program, getting package com.sun.javadoc does not exist

Tags: java, maven, doclet

I'm trying to write a simple Java doclet program where it uses **com.sun.javadoc** package.

And I **also imported the tools.jar as a dependency for the project**. And I can run the application without a problem and the desired results can be obtained.

But when I'm trying to compile the project using maven it gives some errors and will fail the build as well.

```
[ERROR] /home/xxx/xxx/Check.java:[20,33] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class RootDoc
location: class com.sic.checkers.Check
[ERROR] /home/xxx/xxx/Check.java:[26,39] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class PackageDoc
location: class com.sic.checkers.Check
[ERROR] /home/xxx/xxx/ListTags.java:[3,1] package com.sun.javadoc does not exist
[ERROR] /home/xxx/xxx/ListTags.java:[6,33] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class RootDoc
location: class com.sic.checkers.ListTags
[ERROR] /home/xxx/xxx/ListTags.java:[12,39] cannot find symbol
symbol:   class ClassDoc
location: class com.sic.checkers.ListTags
```

I check other [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40804419/not-able-to-run-a-simple-doclet-program-package-com-sun-javadoc-does-not-exist) but they seems to have no solutions for this as well.

What can be the problem here !

Answer (score 3):

I somehow managed to solve this problem and compile and build the code using maven. Did it with the help of [this thread](https://github.com/DavidWhitlock/PortlandStateJava/issues/3). And @GuyKhmel also suggested to add missing dependencies to the pom.xml.

Added a dependency for the project.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
        <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you don't have the dependencies configured under `<dependency>` tag in your pom.xml file.

Could you paste it in pastebin.com and paste here?

You could read some more here: [Maven: Introduction to Dependency Mechanism](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

Comment: Yep. But problem was to know what dependency to add there.